# Where can I find global spatial data for net primary productivity (NPP)?

Tags: data, spatial-database

Where can I find a reliable source of global spatial data for net primary productivity (NPP)?

I have looked and looked but have met various road blocks.

Comment: Self-expanatory, except for the definition.  Please edit the question to contain appropriate links and qualify "looked and looked" with places you have looked.

Answer (score 1):

what are your desired formats and resolution (temporal and spatial)? A quick search found many global products derived from MODIS, e.g.:

Gross Primary Productivity 8-Day L4 Global 1km
https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod17a2

Terra/MODIS Net Primary Production Yearly L4 Global 1km
https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod17a3

UMT MODIS GPP/NPP Project (MOD17)
http://www.ntsg.umt.edu/project/mod17

For the USGS LP DAAC products, [this page](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/data_access) describes options for data access